# Type specific IDs with FlowType

Tags: flowtype

I would like to define an entity map such that the keys must always be IDs of some other object of a specified type. The desired usage would be something like:

```
export type Id<T> = {
  id: string
};

export type Foo = Id<Foo> & {
  val: number
};

// type Foo is now {id: Id<Foo>, val: number}

export type Bar = Id<Bar> & {
  val: number
};

// type Bar is now {id: Id<Bar>, val: number}

// FooMap should only be able to store objects of type foo, referenced by 
// IDs of type Id<Foo>
export type FooMap = {
  [key: Id<Foo>]: Foo
};

const foo1: Foo = { id: "foo1", val: 1 };
const foo2: Foo = { id: "foo2", val: 2 };
const bar1: Bar = { id: "bar1", val: 3 };

// This would pass type checking:
const fooMap: FooMap = {
  [foo1.id]: foo1,
  [foo2.id]: foo2
};

// But this would fail type checking:
const badMap: FooMap = {
  [bar1.id]: foo1
};
```

My use case is that I want to have a normalized object structure that manages relationships via IDs. But since the IDs are all of the same underlying type (e.g., `string` or `number`), it would be possible to accidentally code something like the `badMap` example above. I'm hoping FlowType can help prevent that by enforcing that I only ever reference the correct ID type when I'm programmatically constructing my maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, I think you want a single case tagged union type to represent the various IDs that you're using - here's an example of what that is in F#: [Single Case Discriminated Unions](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/).

If I understand you correctly, you want to create maps like `Map<FooId, Foo>`, where `fooMap[someFooId]` can only contain a `Foo` object. But since `FooId` might be the same type as `BarId`, you can potentially have `someBarId: Foo` in the map. You want Flow to typecheck cases where that's might happen.

Unfortunately, I don't believe there's an easy way to do that right now in Flow, since it lacks single case tagged unions. In F# you could do something like this:

```
type FooId = FooId of string
type BarId = BarId of string

type Id<'T> = Id of 'T // you'd pass in FooId as the type

type Foo = {
    id: Id<FooId>;
    value: string;
}

type Bar = {
    id: Id<BarId>;
    value: string;
}

let foo: Foo = { id = Id (FooId "12345"); value = "fooVal" }
let bar: Bar = { id = Id (BarId "12345"); value = "barVal" }
let fooMap =
    Map.empty<Id<FooId>, Foo>
    |> Map.add (Id (BarId "12345")) foo
```

The closest thing I could get was something like this in JavaScript. The problem with this is that the type error occurs at the definition of `FooId`/`BarId`. We get:

```
string literal `FooId`. Expected string literal `BarId`, got `FooId` instead
string literal `BarId`. Expected string literal `FooId`, got `BarId` instead
```

**The JavaScript:**

```
type FooId = "FooId";
type BarId = "BarId";
type Id<T> = {
  id: string;
  type: T
};

type Foo = {
  id: Id<FooId>, 
  val: any
};

type Bar = {
  id: Id<BarId>, // get type error here
  val: any
};

type FooMap = {
  [key: Id<FooId>]: Foo // get type error here
};

const fooIdBuilder = (id): Id<FooId> => ({ id, type: "FooId" });
const barIdBuilder = (id): Id<BarId> => ({ id, type: "BarId" });

const foo1: Foo = {
  id: fooIdBuilder("12345"),
  val: "fooval"
};

const foo2: Foo = {
  id: fooIdBuilder("23456"),
  val: "fooval"
};

const bar1: Bar = {
  id: barIdBuilder("23456"),
  val: "barval"
};

const fooMap: FooMap = {};
fooMap[foo1.id] = foo1;
fooMap[bar1.id] = foo2;
```

You can copy and paste this into [Try Flow](https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAkgEygXigbwD4CgpQCWyAXFAM7ABOhAdgOYA0+RyAKuBGQETxLLdc2AL65coSFABCAQyop0WPAWJlKNBsxXtOPWfIFDR4zrASLMLVWf5aoANxkAbMjNohcwgNxiJ0fRZWpNJyKHaOLlBuHt6+pnwAsjJggQQA2gDWECBkfCgAurkInj64AMZwtJRQAGYIKFIAroROyBBUigAUxACURfzoAHxQnZisjKwckDx5AlDCPT4VVcBQAEahyE0tbR0Y3ch9IQZDI2PEE8RTXFDc+ijc84tiy9V1cACM-amsZO8NzVa7U63A+ACYAMwAFgArNweuFnDx3hFBLFypU3ggwd8MJZtH96ltAbsQZDYQA2eGIyLcFHONGlV6rDZUL7HH7WVkAnbA7jkmFUhEsCI8VmokovTGrd5JMD9OUWWKy5Jpf7E3lUEHg6Fwnr5RTvD4+FVgNLcjVArWggXwg0Yd5g0piF1AA)

Comment: Yep, your answer is just about where I ended up in my thinking. I agree that my original use case doesn't currently seem possible in Flow, and further agree that the error report at the declaration site, rather than use site, is misleading. :) Thanks for taking the time to put together the example code!